# Problem using SQL Agent to run SSIS Packages - fails with "DTSER_FAILURE(1)"

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, ssis, sql-server-agent

I have an SSIS Package stored in the MSDB database which works fine when I execute it. It will run under SA account or will use Windows security.

I want to schedule this job to run with SQL Agent, but when I do I get a strange error and whatever configuration I try it fails with the following error:

**Executed as user: SERVER\SYSTEM. on returned DTSER_FAILURE (1).  Started:  09:25:03  Finished: 09:25:04  Elapsed:  0.61 seconds.  The package execution failed.  The step failed.**

The SSIS package itself is reading and writing data to a remote server,  but I don't think that it gets that far during the package execution.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You will need to grant the account running the SQL Agent windows service the necessary permissions.

Alternatively, you can run individual job steps under another security context by specifying a proxy account to run the step.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this KB:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/918760

Especially useful is the last section about error logging - on how to get more detaled error information.

Answer (score 1):

Use master
Go

sp_configure 'allow updates',0
go

reconfigure with override
go

Answer (score 0):

Similar issue on `SQL 2008 R2 DB`  error mentioned below....

Checked the Maintenance Plan and found the subplans were not set to select any particular database, for which the action needs to be performed! And I found one of the databases **offline**.

**Dogh Moment!**

Also i set the **Ignore Offline Databases**.

i re-run the Job & it was successful.

Error Details as below.

> Executed as user: **********. Microsoft (R) SQL Server Execute Package
>   Utility  Version 10.50.4000.0 for 64-bit  Copyright (C) Microsoft
>   Corporation 2010. All rights reserved.    Started:  9:53:00 AM 
>   Progress: 2012-11-12 09:53:00.82     Source:
>   {108E79C2-F5AA-4698-8DD4-**********}      Executing query "DECLARE
>   @Guid UNIQUEIDENTIFIER      EXECUTE msdb..sp...".: 100% complete  End
>   Progress  DTExec: The package execution returned DTSER_FAILURE (1). 
>   Started:  9:53:00 AM  Finished: 9:53:01 AM  Elapsed:  0.734 seconds. 
>   The package execution failed.  The step failed.